# Adding files to a file[] statement in java

Tags: java

Hello members of stackoverflow

I need some help with adding files from a directory to a bunch of files (File[])

So basically i want to add all the files in a directory to the following group of files:

```
File[] contents = {};
```

The user of my application will select a directory and i want that directories contents to be added to the above group of files ('contents I'm not sure how this is done because it doesn't have a simple 'add' method like an ArrayList/List does.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to be able to easily add to a list after it's created, use a List, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`File.listFiles()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29):

```
File dir = new File("/somedir");
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, didn't realize it was such a simple solution. I was trying to use a for loop to add files but this is much better :)

Comment: Taking a look at the API documentation is always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
    try
    {
        File folder = new File(FOLDER_NAME);
        File[] contents = folder.listFiles();
    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("[Error] Folder not Found"); 
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate ?

Comment: The `File` constructor throws only a `NullPointerException` when the argument is `null`. On the other hand `listFiles` throws a `SecurityException`. None of the exceptions say anything about the file/directory not being found.

Comment: The constructor is not validating the path. From doc - It "Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname." So even `File f = new File("");` will execute without throwing any exception.

Comment: Nope, just checked again. It throws an exception if you have an incorrect path. Try it yourself once.

Comment: I doubt. Why do you think then `File.exists()` method is there for?